# How to make screen size 100 % even we minimize the screen in vb.net

Tags: asp.net

I have one statistical report for displaying data month wise and year wise in a bar graph. For this report SSRS is used to display the data. A count is displaying when we mouse over each bar of the the graph.

When the screen size of the report is the full window size of the monitor (i.e. 100%), the data is correctly displaying when I mouse over the cursor on each bar of the graph.

My problem is that when I minimize the size of the report screen data is not showing correctly in each bar of the graph. The wrong value is displayed.

Comment: What about showing us your code ? At least the part that doesn't work correctly ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please check out the page on [how to ask questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help./how-to-ask) in order to get the best help. In particular - you need to show your VB code along with any debugging you've done so far.  You might also try making a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!